# Transfer/move added data down (instead of appending)

Tags: excel, vba, data-entry

I have the following macro which works fine for me in terms of adding data and new lines:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim emptyRow As Long

  'Make WOTracker active
  Sheets("WOTracker").Activate

  'Determine emptyRow
   emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

  'Transfer information
   Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
   Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TextBox2.Value
End Sub
```

What I need help with is modifying the code so that instead of adding data below existing rows (to a new line), it pushes the previously added data down. So what was in row 2 goes to row 3 and the new data is inserted into Row 2.

Comment: So, you want to insert new data at row 2, right?

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a new row at `Range("A2")` and the change your last row variable to a `2` to signify `row 2`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WOTracker") 
        .Cells(2, 1).EntireRow.insert
        .Cells(2, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(2, 5).Value = TextBox2.Value
    End With
End Sub
```